# Output showing null in AVExportSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetexportsession

I cannot able to get output for a video file,

```
    self.exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc]
                          initWithAsset:self.videoAsset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
    // Implementation continues.



     self.exportSession.outputURL = furl;
```

`self.videoAsset` is :

`<AVURLAsset: 0x7faf62e65000, URL = https://video.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t43.1792-2/12529221_1698805023741577_254337559_n.mp4?efg=eyJybHIiOjE1MDAsInJsYSI6MjM3MywidmVuY29kZV90YWciOiJzdmVfaGQifQ%3D%3D&rl=1500&vabr=365&oh=4c6901578cd1316b5d2c38a127d8f165&oe=571B3BC3>`

Comment: What's the value of `furl`?

Comment: its NSURL i got the problem solved thanks